# npm ERR! failed at the myfrontend@3.3.0 build script

Tags: node.js, npm, docker-compose

I just got a new laptop for work, and trying to set it up for work. As I tried to run a service-build in my terminal as the command of

```
"./data-management/run_update_version && docker-compose -f docker-compose/docker-compose.yml build"
```

I got the error as below.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myfrontend@3.3.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myfrontend@3.3.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-23T06_10_10_366Z-debug.log
```

I have tried many solutions such as clean cache, redo the npm install, but none of them worked. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, I figured out that this error means that there is no enough memory in the system. What I did is to go into docker desktop setting, and increase the memory, and that solved everything.